# Flutter : how to create text over image, that is resizable with handle 4 dots

Tags: image, flutter, editor, photo

How can achieve below resizeable text editor over the photo?

Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stack` Widget

Official Docs:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html#widgets.Stack.1